# Advantage to Declaring Constructors and Destructors inside vs. outside of the class?

Tags: c++, class, oop, constructor, destructor

I've been following along a class about constructors, destructors and constructor overloading in C++. (Granted, it's from 2018, I don't know if that changes anything.) Is there any reason that he defines constructors and everything else outside of the class (still inside the same .cpp file)? What's the difference between:

```
const std::string unk = "unknown";
const std::string prefix = "copy-of-";

class Human {

    std::string _name = "";
    int _height = 0;
    int _age = 0;
    
public: 

    Human();
    Human(const std::string& name, const int& height, const int& age);
    Human(const Human& right);
    Human& operator = (const Human& right);
    ~Human();
    void print() const;
    
};

Human::Human() : _name(unk), _height(0), _age(0) {
    puts("Default Constructor");
}

Human::Human(const std::string& name, const int& height, const int& age)
    : _name(name), _height(height), _age(age) {
    puts("Constructor w/ arguments");
}

Human::Human(const Human& right) {
    puts("Copy Constructor");
    _name = prefix + right._name;
    _height = right._height;
    _age = right._age;
}

Human& Human::operator = (const Human& right) {
    puts("Copy Operator!");
    if (this != &right) {
        _name = prefix + right._name;
        _height = right._height;
        _age = right._age;
    }
}

Human::~Human() {
    printf("Destructor: %s ", _name.c_str());
}

void Human::print() const {
    printf("Hello, I'm %s, %dcm tall and %d years old.\n", _name.c_str(), _height, _age);
}
```

and

```
const std::string unk = "unknown";
const std::string prefix = "copy-of-";

class Human {

    std::string _name = "";
    int _height = 0;
    int _age = 0;
    
public: 
    
    Human() : _name(unk), _height(0), _age(0) {
        puts("Default Constructor");
    }
    
    Human(const std::string& name, const int& height, const int& age)
        : _name(name), _height(height), _age(age) {
        puts("Constructor w/ arguments");
    }

    Human(const Human& right) {
        puts("Copy Constructor");
        _name = prefix + right._name;
        _height = right._height;
        _age = right._age;
    }

    Human& operator = (const Human& right) {
        puts("Copy Operator!");
        if (this != &right) {
            _name = prefix + right._name;
            _height = right._height;
            _age = right._age;
        }
    }

    ~Human() {
        printf("Destructor: %s ", _name.c_str());
    }

    void print() const {
        printf("Hello, I'm %s, %dcm tall and %d years old.\n", _name.c_str(), _height, _age);
    }
};
```

since both work perfectly fine?
Wouldn't it be more efficient (readeable) to declare everything *inside* the class on the first go?

Comment: From the human point of view - the interface readability at a single glance. From the technical point of view - inline vs not inline member fuctions.

Comment: There is no technical difference between these two, it is a personal preference issue which you prefer.

Comment: The technical difference appears when you actually move the function definitions into a separate source file. If you make all function definitions visible in the same header unit that provides their declarations, it makes those functions more easily inlined but it also means that more files potentially have to be recompiled if you make a change to a definition.

Comment: @Caleth There actually *is* a technical difference. Functions defined in the class declaration are implicitly `inline`. Functions defined outside the class declaration are *not*. Whether or not the `inline`ness (and thus linkage) differences actually matter in this case is a different question. Also, functions defined outside the class declaration are, by definition, never *trivial* (even if you `= default;` them).

Comment: IMHO, if you want people to see the content of the constructor or the destructor, place them in the class.  I prefer to put most of my methods into a source file, so If I make a change to the method, other source files don't need to be rebuilt.

Comment: *Wouldn't it be more efficient (readeable) to declare everything inside the class on the first go?*  In my opinion, no; I think it is much more readable to have the class member function implementations separate from the class declaration.  But that's a matter of opinion.  From the code I've seen in the wild, both styles are commonplace.  Quite often, even both styles in the same source file.  Jesper nicely summarized the salient differences from the language & compiler perspective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes a difference if you are going to be using the class `Human` in (possibly many) different .cpp files. In that case the information regarding the structure of the class needs to be placed in a separate header (i.e. .h ) file.  Behind the scenes, the information from the .h file is automatically copied to every .cpp file that contains a `#include "Human.h"` statement somewhere.  This needs to be done for every .cpp file that uses the class `Human` before it can be compiled ( and later linked ).

The information needed externally from `Human.h` will be the class definition, which, at a minimum, contains all data members and method declarations of the class `Human`.  If the class definition also contains method definitions, these will be duplicated for each .cpp file in which the header is included.

Now you should see why it might not be a good idea to place very long method definitions *inside* the class definition.  In some cases duplication of methods can increase performance, but its usually better to do that using compiler optimization settings.  The problem with having too much function code in the header file is it can greatly increase the compilation time.

As constructors and destructors are usually short, there is virtually no functional performance difference in placing them inside vs outside the class.  If you are developing a module that will be included as part of a much bigger piece of software though, sometimes it's a good idea to design your header file as *documentation* for your module's API.  You don't want to overwhelm someone using your module with tons of code in the header.  Instead, just document what the classes and methods do with comments and place the routines themselves, even short ones, in the .cpp file.

When you are just playing around with a single-file project it makes no difference.  In multi-file projects it will make a difference.  That's the gist of it.

Edited to add one more thing:

When your class has private member attributes ( `_age` for instance is private by default inside your `Human` class ) that some code in a different file needs access to, the class will need a `get_age()` method.  Something like...

```
int get_age() { return _age; }
```

If another file has some code like...

```
double getAverageAge( const std::vector<Human>& staff_directory )
{
    int age_sum = 0;
    for ( const Human& human : staff_directory )
    {
        age_sum += human.get_age();
    }
    return static_cast<double>( age_sum ) / staff_directory.size();
}
```

and the staff directory contains a thousand or more `Human` objects, there will be some performance benefit to keeping the `get_age()` function in the header.

If `get_age()` is defined in the header file inside the class, the compiler will effectively duplicate the code everywhere `get_age()` appears, even in a different compilation unit ( i.e. code from another .cpp file that happens to include `Human.h` ).  This is called automatic inlining.

So, very trivial functions like getters or setters should stay inside the class definition in the header file, especially if they will likely be called inside a loop in some other .cpp file.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
class Foo {
public:
  Foo() { }
};
```

is equivalent to this:

```
class Foo {
public:
  Foo();
};

inline Foo::Foo()
{
}
```

Without the `inline`, they are not equivalent: a non-inline definition of the constructor is being defined. If you put that into a header file and include it in multiple places, it will violate the One Definition Rule.

When you define the functions in the middle of the class declaration, you are writing inline definitions.

A reason to move them outside of the class declaration (while keeping them `inline` and in the same file) would be that the class declaration is cluttered. You'd like a tidy class declaration which only declares.

Reasons to move move member function definitions outside of the class declaration as non-line definitions (and, typically, placing them into a separate implementation file) is that the functions are too large to be inline functions, or that they reveal implementation details, or create unwanted build dependencies: the inlined behavior is likely going to change, which then requires recompiling everything which uses the class.

Speaking of dependencies, non-inline member functions declared in a separate file have the freedom to make use of dependencies that are not declared in the header.

This header mentions no stream library:

```
// Header file:
class Hello {
public:
  Hello();
};
```

The implementation file brings that in for itself:

```
#include <iostream>

Hello::Hello()
{
  std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
}
```

If this function were inlined in the class declaration, the header would have to include `<iostream>`, foisting that material on everything which includes it.

We can change `Hello` to send the message to some completely different I/O library without having to recompile any code which relies on `Hello`.